# Why am I getting a type error between two integers

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to make the shopping cart of an e-commerce store and I've modelled the database and everything but I keep on getting a type error.

**Storefront/Models.py/Product**

```
from django.db import models
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalFiled(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity= models.IntegerField(default=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now I'm working on the shopping cart view to take quantity from users and to check if it is more than available goods.

**Cart/views.py**
(jumping some codes)

```
from Storefront.models import Product
try:
   quantity=int(request.data['quantity'])
if quantity > Product.quantity:
   raise NotAcceptable('quantity more than available in stock')
```

The error code I'm getting is:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'DeferredAttribute'

The quantity being inputed is being converted to an integer and Product.quantity is an integerfield so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not running any query. What do you expect `Product.quantity` to be?

Comment: Yes, `Product.quantity` is an IntegerField. That means, a part of **the class** that is used to make sure that each of your individual `Product`s has a `quantity`, and that this `quantity` is an integer. But if you want to compare the requested quantity to the quantity of some `Product`, then you have to say **which** `Product` to use. This code is like asking whether a flower is red. Well, *some* are.

Comment: how about trying `int(Product.quantity)` to cast it as an integer? For example `if int(quantity) > int(Product.quantity):`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In this case, I think you would be better off working through a Django tutorial to make sure you understand the general concepts. You might also need to brush up on a general Python tutorial, to make sure you understand classes, instances and attributes properly.

Comment: @BlackRaven that makes no sense in this situation, and also more generally it is *rare* that "try to convert the data to another type" (Python does not have real casting) is the correct answer to `TypeError`. A `TypeError` is a sign that you are trying to do something that doesn't make sense, and it is usually because one or more of the inputs is just wrongly derived.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi. You are checking between integer and class attribute. You should check between `quantity` and `some_product.quantity` where `some_product` is an instance or object of Product model (class).

Comment: I've solved the problem guys. Yes I didn't drop the full code I did run a query for those asking but where I made the mistake was with the variable holding the query and when running the quantity>Product.quantity it was meant to be product.quantity small letter and capital letter mistake. Thanks for your help guys 